# How to format a multidimensionnal array depending on it's cell values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to format an array in my Excel sheet. The goel is to kinda do the opposite of a `SUMIF`, for each element of my table and it's number `x`, I'd like to create `x` rows of this element in an other table.
As a screenshot can be more explicit than a long dialog, here is what I want to achieve: [image: Excel table]

If there are `0` occurence of the fruit, it shouldn't be displayed in the `GOAL`table.

The `Base` and `Goal` tables are hard written in my excel sheet and serve as an example, the `Current Result` table is made with this formula:

**French version (I'm using a French Excel):**

```
{=SIERREUR(
 INDEX(
  B$5:B$100;
  PETITE.VALEUR(
   SI(
    SI(
     ($C$5:$C$100>0);
     VRAI;
      FAUX
    );
    LIGNE(B$5:B$100)-LIGNE(B$5)+1
   );
   LIGNES(B$5:B5)
  )
 );
 ""
)}
```

**English Version (havn't tested it):**

```
{=IFERROR(
 INDEX(
  B$5:B$100;
  SMALL(
   IF(
    IF(
     ($C$5:$C$100>0);
     TRUE;
      FALSE
    );
    ROW(B$5:B$100)-ROW(B$5)+1
   );
   ROWS(B$5:B5)
  )
 );
 ""
)}
```

Can you give me some hints on how I may achieve this? I there any way to do it without using VBA and only formulas?

**Note:**
I've been asked to do this at work, I never used Excel in my whole life and know nothing about VBA. That's why I'm a bit lost with this task. I usually code in Python or C++. I'm using Excel 2010.

Comment: Looks like the researches I made before asking this question were not good enough, here is a possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395454/excel-vba-automation-copy-row-x-number-of-times-based-on-cell-value). Gonna try to find my own solution based on this.

Comment: Ok. Let me know if you still decide you want a purely formula-based solution after reading that post.

Comment: I managed to do what I wanted using VBA, thank you for your time.

Comment: Ok, thanks for getting back to me and glad you got a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve my goal using VBA, here is the code I used:

```
Public Sub GenerateTable()
    ' This routing will copy rows based on the quantity to a new sheet.
    Dim rngSinglecell As Range
    Dim rngQuantityCells As Range
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim countCell As Integer

    ' Set this for the range where the Quantity column exists. This works only if there are no empty cells
    Set rngQuantityCells = Sheets("Feuil3").Range("C5", Sheets("Feuil3").Range("C5").End(xlDown))

    countCell = 4
    For Each rngSinglecell In rngQuantityCells
        ' Check if this cell actually contains a number
        If IsNumeric(rngSinglecell.Value) Then
            ' Check if the number is greater than 0
            If rngSinglecell.Value > 0 Then
                ' Copy this row as many times as .value
                For intCount = 1 To rngSinglecell.Value
                    ' Copy the row into the next emtpy row in sheet2
                    countCell = countCell + 1
                    Intersect(Range(rngSinglecell.Address).EntireRow, Columns("B:D")).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Feuil3").Range("G" & CStr(countCell))
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

And here is the output:

[image: Result]

Solution based on Matt's answer in [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395454/excel-vba-automation-copy-row-x-number-of-times-based-on-cell-value).