# Excel VBA- copy and insert row based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, rows

I'm trying to accomplish this:

column G      ========>  new    column G

```
2                            1

                             2

2                            1

                             2

1                            1

1                            1

2                            1

                             2
```

I've looked at many different questions to answer this but I believe my code is incorrect because I want to copy the entire row when initially G = 2 and insert it directly beneath, instead of the usual copy it to another sheet in excel.

```
Sub duplicate()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To LastRow
If Range("G" & i).Value = "2" Then
    Range(Cells(Target.Row, "G"), Cells(Target.Row, "G")).Copy
    Range(Cells(Target.Row, "G"), Cells(Target.Row, "G")).EntireRow.Insert    Shift:=xlDown
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Thank you so much to any and all help!!

[Excel VBA automation - copy row "x" number of times based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395454/excel-vba-automation-copy-row-x-number-of-times-based-on-cell-value)

Comment: Are you trying to copy it or are you wanting to number the new column based on the values in the old column? I don't quite understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to insert a new row not a new column. I want to change the value in column G to either 1 or 2 based on the number that exists in it now. If it helps, my initial column had time values in it ("0:59:00" etc) and I changed them according to this rule: If Column G = 1:00:00, ignore and move to next row
• If Column G > 1:00:00, make it Hour 2. I now want to add on to this part by copying the current row and make the new row Hour 2. I was having problems with the code in its entirety so I was trying to break it up.

Comment: This was my first part of the code: Sub categorizeHours()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Time1 As Date
    Time1 = TimeValue("01:00:00")
    LastRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Range("F" & i).Value < Time1 Then
    Range("G" & i).Value = "1"
    ElseIf Range("B" & i).Value > Time1 Then
    Range("G" & i).Value = "2"
    End If
    Next i
    End Sub

Comment: When inserting rows, *always* start at the bottom and work up. This avoids the invalidation of your *i* variable according to the new current position after a row has been inserted. Additionally, *LastRow* doesn't have to be adjusted for all of the inserted rows. Change the *For* statement to `For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1` and see if that will work (once you actually define *LastRow* and stuff a *1* into the G column of the new row).

Comment: Dennis, your reverse directional advice is solid if the code does the inserts one at a time. My approach below does all of the inserts in one shot, which makes the direction moot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub ExpandRecords()

    Dim i As Long, s As String
    Const COL = "G"

    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, COL).End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, COL) = 2 Then
            s = s & "," & Cells(i, COL).Address
        End If
    Next
    If Len(s) Then
        Range(Mid$(s, 2)).EntireRow.Insert
        For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, COL).End(xlUp).Row
            If Cells(i, COL) = vbNullString Then
                Cells(i, COL).Value = 1
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```