# Duplicating Rows in Excel That Will Exceed Row Limit?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I am trying to use the below VBA code to duplicate rows that I have based on a count column. I have 279,754 rows that would expand to be 1,969,671 rows. I know excel 2016 has a row limit of 1,048,576. I am using Excel 2016 and I know it has 'Get and Transform', is there a way I could use this to get past my issue? My final output format will need to be a CSV if that's of any use. Any help greatly appreciated. [Source page of VBA code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395454/excel-vba-automation-copy-row-x-number-of-times-based-on-cell-value)

```
Public Sub CopyData()
' This routing will copy rows based on the quantity to a new sheet.
Dim rngSinglecell As Range
Dim rngQuantityCells As Range
Dim intCount As Integer

' Set this for the range where the Quantity column exists. This works only if there are no empty cells
Set rngQuantityCells = Range("D1", Range("D1").End(xlDown))

For Each rngSinglecell In rngQuantityCells
    ' Check if this cell actually contains a number
    If IsNumeric(rngSinglecell.Value) Then
        ' Check if the number is greater than 0
        If rngSinglecell.Value > 0 Then
            ' Copy this row as many times as .value
            For intCount = 1 To rngSinglecell.Value
                ' Copy the row into the next emtpy row in sheet2
                Range(rngSinglecell.Address).EntireRow.Copy Destination:= Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)                                
                ' The above line finds the next empty row.

            Next
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, did you try saving the file that will hold the data as .csv before doing the clonning?

Comment: No because then I wouldn't be able to run my macro? Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: The link you provided has five or so different answers with code, so it is useless.  I suggest you develop a method to process your data in chunks, and write each chunk to the csv file, using an append type operation.  You could use the `Open` method, or the `FileSystemObject`

Comment: I added the actual VBA code that I am trying to use, I have successfully tested it on a small number of rows.

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld has given you an easy way to solve your problem.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I'll read open some on _Open_ and _FileSystemObject_ and hopefully they'll solve my problem. Thanks