# Copy Row and paste X amount of times dependent on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that needs to copy a row and paste it (values, not formula) x times dependent on value in column A (quantity). This needs to be repeated for an 'infinite' amount of rows. Once this is done column A needs to be deleted.

There are similar questions to this but none seem to work for me, my macro also needs to delete two sheets and save the file as a CSV with a given name. I have the save and give name based on cell values just not the copy and paste.

---

So I have only used VBA for about two weeks so i am struggling: 
I have tried this and that and i can get the odd code to work by itself but never with the rest of the code.

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Path As String
Dim Filename1 As String
Dim Filename2 As String
Path = "C:\Users\BergA2\Desktop\CSV Usage Upload\ "

Filename1 = Range("B1")
Filename2 = Range("D1")

I imagine the code would go in here: values for quantity are taken from sheet1 and moved into sheet3 using a simple formula 

Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
Sheets("Sheet1").Delete

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & Filename1 & "-" & Filename2 & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV


End Sub
```

---

Input ( more then just two columns)

```
Quantity User   ... 
1        A      ...
3        B      ...
0        C      ...
```

Output:

```
User    ...
A       ...
B       ...
B       ...
B       ...
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Like... Googling "Excel VBA Copy Row x number of times based on cell value"?  I suspect not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA automation - copy row "x" number of times based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395454/excel-vba-automation-copy-row-x-number-of-times-based-on-cell-value)

Comment: Hey Marc, I have and I have seen that example and it didnt seem to work with the rest of my code, i genuinely have been trying for the last week to figure it out as to why it doesnt work with the rest of my code. 'r.Copy .Range("A" & n)' seems to be the problem every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyBasedOnColumnA()
    Dim numberCopies As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Dim sht as Worksheet
    Set sht = Sheets("add sheet name")

    currentRow = 2

    Do While Not IsEmpty(sht.Cells(currentRow, 1))
        'determine how often to copy the current row
        numberCopies = sht.Cells(currentRow, 1)

        'copy that many times
        For j = 2 To numberCopies
            sht.Rows(currentRow).copy
            sht.Rows(currentRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown

            'increment the counter, otherwise you also copy all the rows just input
            currentRow = currentRow + 1
        Next j

        'move to next row
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
    Loop

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    sht.Columns(1).Delete
End Sub
```

I'm assuming you don't want to copy the header. You can define in which row you want to start by setting the `currentRow` variable. Also I assumed that you don't have anything import stored in column A.

Comment: Hey, so this is working a charm by itself havnt tried it with the rest of the code, however the macro button is on sheet1 and the data is on sheet3 also when the quantity is 0 the row needs to delete. Could you help with that?

Comment: `Cells(1,1)` always references the cell A1 in the current Sheet, if you want to reference cells in other sheets, you can do that like so: `Sheets("sheetname").Cells(1,1)`

Even better use a variable, of type Worksheet. That way you only have to change it once of the sheet changes.

Comment: Considering the code is going in between some other code do i need to state where to loop back to?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean.
If you add my sub into your code you can call from any other sub or function by writing 'copyBasedOnColumnA`.

That will tell Excel to execute my code, once it's finished it will run any code that comes afterwards. You can use the debugger to follow along line by line using F8.

Comment: I just popped your code first at the start of the whole macro and it runs beautifully thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to be of help, you should mark the question as answered now

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have your headers in the first row.

```
Public Function ReturnCol(ByVal searchString As String) As Integer
Dim rg As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows("1:1").Select
Set rg = Selection.Find(What:=searchString, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

If rg Is Nothing Then
    ReturnCol = 0
    Exit Function
Else
    ReturnCol = rg.Column
End If

End Function
Sub collect()
Dim col_pos As Integer
Dim usedrows As Long

Dim i As Integer
Dim user As String
Dim quant As Integer

Dim counter As Long
' Assuming headers are in the first row

' Calculate until which point to loop
usedrows = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

' Find the positions of the headers (column numbers)
quant_col_pos = ReturnCol("Quantity")
user_col_pos = ReturnCol("User")


counter = 0
If quant_col_pos <> 0 Then
    For i = 2 To usedrows
        user = Cells(i, user_col_pos).Value
        quant = Cells(i, quant_col_pos).Value
        Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

        If i = 2 Then
            Cells(1, 1).Value = "User"
        End If
        ' starting filling values from the 2nd row but somewhere need to remember
        'which one was the last row used therefore counter is used

        For x = 2 + counter To 1 + quant + counter
            ' first column
            Cells(x, 1).Value = user
        Next x
        counter = quant + counter
        Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

    Next i

End If
End Sub
```